# Groupby mutate equivalent in pandas/python using tidydata principles

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

My dataframe resembles the following:

```
group_var1 = ['A1','A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2']
group_var2 = ['B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2']
group_var3 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2']

value = np.arange(len(group_var1))

ex_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group_var1' : group_var1,
    'group_var2' : group_var2,
    'group_var3' : group_var3,
    'value' : value
})
```

which should produce the following when called:

```
    group_va1   group_va2   group_va3   value
0   A1  B1  C1  0
1   A1  B1  C2  1
2   A1  B1  C1  2
3   A1  B1  C2  3
4   A1  B2  C1  4
5   A1  B2  C2  5
6   A1  B2  C1  6
7   A1  B2  C2  7
8   A2  B1  C1  8
9   A2  B1  C2  9
10  A2  B1  C1  10
11  A2  B1  C2  11
12  A2  B2  C1  12
13  A2  B2  C2  13
14  A2  B2  C1  14
15  A2  B2  C2  15
```

My goal is to group the DataFrame by columns `group_var1`, `group_var2`, and `group_var3`, and then calculate the mean `value` within each group, and add a new row `mean_ex` to this existing DataFrame with these results. In R this could be accomplished by `ex_df %>% group_by(c(group_var1, group_var2, group_var3)) %>% mutate(mean_ex = mean(value))` which automatically handles assigning the new value to the respective rows.

I have found ways to summarize the DataFrame by aggregating all of the values within each group into only the mean value (`ex_df.groupby(['group_var1', 'group_var2', 'group_var3']).mean()`), but I want the mean value to be a new column in my existing DataFrame, not a df of smaller dimensions. My desired output can be found below, and was achieved by using pd.merge() on my original df and my previously described undesired aggregated table:

```
    group_var1  group_var2  group_var3  value   mean_ex
0   A1  B1  C1  0   1
1   A1  B1  C2  1   2
2   A1  B1  C1  2   1
3   A1  B1  C2  3   2
4   A1  B2  C1  4   5
5   A1  B2  C2  5   6
6   A1  B2  C1  6   5
7   A1  B2  C2  7   6
8   A2  B1  C1  8   9
9   A2  B1  C2  9   10
10  A2  B1  C1  10  9
11  A2  B1  C2  11  10
12  A2  B2  C1  12  13
13  A2  B2  C2  13  14
14  A2  B2  C1  14  13
15  A2  B2  C2  15  14
```

My question is, is there any way to achieve this desired output without having to create a separate dataframe that then gets merged back onto the original? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform` and `assign`:

```
ex_df.assign(
    mean_val = 
    ex_df
    .groupby(["group_var1", "group_var2",  "group_var3"])
    .value
    .transform('mean')
)

   group_var1 group_var2 group_var3  value  mean_val
0          A1         B1         C1      0         1
1          A1         B1         C2      1         2
2          A1         B1         C1      2         1
3          A1         B1         C2      3         2
4          A1         B2         C1      4         5
5          A1         B2         C2      5         6
6          A1         B2         C1      6         5
7          A1         B2         C2      7         6
8          A2         B1         C1      8         9
9          A2         B1         C2      9        10
10         A2         B1         C1     10         9
11         A2         B1         C2     11        10
12         A2         B2         C1     12        13
13         A2         B2         C2     13        14
14         A2         B2         C1     14        13
15         A2         B2         C2     15        14
```

**Explanation**
Pandas `assign` is the rough equivalent of `dplyr::mutate`, and `transform` broadcasts the grouping operation across all the initial rows of an input, rather than simply calling an aggregation function after `groupby`.

Something like `df.groupby('a').x.mean()` will result in a single value per grouped index, set, which is the analog to `dplyr::summarise`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it in the same way in python as you did in R, using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, f, tibble, mutate, mean, group_by
>>> 
>>> group_var1 = ['A1','A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2'
, 'A2']
>>> group_var2 = ['B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2
', 'B2']
>>> group_var3 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1
', 'C2']
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     group_var1,
...     group_var2,
...     group_var3,
...     value=range(len(group_var1))
... )
>>> 
>>> df >> group_by(
...     f.group_var1, f.group_var2, f.group_var3
... ) >> mutate(
...     mean_ex = mean(f.value)
... )
   group_var1 group_var2 group_var3   value   mean_ex
     <object>   <object>   <object> <int64> <float64>
0          A1         B1         C1       0       1.0
1          A1         B1         C2       1       2.0
2          A1         B1         C1       2       1.0
3          A1         B1         C2       3       2.0
4          A1         B2         C1       4       5.0
5          A1         B2         C2       5       6.0
6          A1         B2         C1       6       5.0
7          A1         B2         C2       7       6.0
8          A2         B1         C1       8       9.0
9          A2         B1         C2       9      10.0
10         A2         B1         C1      10       9.0
11         A2         B1         C2      11      10.0
12         A2         B2         C1      12      13.0
13         A2         B2         C2      13      14.0
14         A2         B2         C1      14      13.0
15         A2         B2         C2      15      14.0

[Groups: group_var1, group_var2, group_var3 (n=8)]
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.